# Statistical test for assessing trends (one-sample)

Tags: small-sample, trend, permutation-test, one-tailed-test

I'm interested in looking at annual trends. The numbers represent the total number of a particular animal species that have been counted in that year. We see a decreasing trend, and I would like to check if the decreasing trend is statistically significant.

```r
       mydf <- data.frame(
        Year = 2016:2020,
        Count = c(21, 36, 26, 13, 5)
        )
```

Someone suggested me to use a permutation test for this by calculating the geometric mean decrease for the data, and see where your observed statistic falls in the distribution.

```r
    set.seed(20210301)
    
    ##Define function for sample
    GeoMeanFun  <- function(Data){
      rnd.sample <- sample(x=Data, size = length(Data), 
      replace = TRUE)
      mean(diff(log(rnd.sample)))
    }
    ##Get 10000 samples with replacement
    mydf.samples <- replicate(10000, GeoMeanFun(mydf$Count))
    
    mydf.observed <- mean(diff(log(mydf$Count)))
    
    ##Check where observed statistic falls in the distribution
    ggplot() +
      ylab("Count") + xlab("Simulated trends") +
      geom_histogram(aes(x = mydf.samples), bins = 20, 
                     fill = "grey", alpha = 0.4, colour = 
      "black") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = mydf.observed, size = 1, 
                 linetype = "dashed", colour = "black") + 
      theme_classic()
```

Now I'm not sure whether I should use a one-tailed or two-tailed test. We are predicting a significant decrease, but I still cannot decide what test to use. Any suggestions for other types of tests would also be appreciated.

Comment: I can make no sense of this: (1) With only three negative differences out of four, there does not seem to be enough information for a nonparametric test of adequate power. (2) Because you're re-sampling with replacement from your data, rather than permuting it. this seems more like a bootstrap procedure than a permutation test.

Comment: If there is an established historical yearly Poisson mean of about $\lambda = 25,$ then the Poisson probability of seeing 5 or fewer in the current year is $P(X \le 5 \,|\lambda=25) = 1.397112e-06 \approx 0.,$ which casts significant doubt that the historical mean persists.

Comment: 1). How does one compare annual trends then? We will always end up with a single number for each year. 
2). I think I don't understand the difference between bootstrapping and permutation? Is permutation based on re-sampling without replacement?

Comment: A permutation test is based on permutation of the sample in various ways. For example, in a two-sample test with $n_1$ and $n_2$ observations per sample, it would permute all $n_1+n_2$ observations with $n_1$ to sample 1 and $n_2$ to sample 2.// Nonparametric bootstrap re-samples $n$ observations by taking samples _with replacement_ of size $n$ from among the original $n.$ // To detect a sequential process going 'out of control' (e.g., $\mu$ or $\sigma$ drifting from specifications, one can use a 'control chart', which you might want to google. // Your basic difficulty is too few obs.